# How to Show the Lat/Long of Marker in a Textbox if it has been clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, leaflet

```
   function getInfo() { 
    $.getJSON("get_info.php", function (data) { 
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng); 
        var marker = new L.Marker(location,{icon:Icon1}); 
           marker.bindPopup(
              data[i].name + "<br>" + 
              data[i].user_date + "<br>" + 
              data[i].user_time + "<br>" + 
              data[i].address + "<br>"
           ).addTo(map);
           marker.on('click', function(e) { // HERE YOU GO
                var ll = marker.getLatLng();
document.querySelector('#userLat').value = ll.lat;
document.querySelector('#userLng').value = ll.lng;
           });
         } 
    }); 
  }
```

My code above works perfectly but I have one question. This will automatically generate marker in the map from database. I just wanna add a function that if the generated marker has been clicked it will show the markers lat/long in two diff textbox. how can i achieved this?

```
<text>Marker Latitude:<text>
<input id="userLat" type="text" name="userlat"  />
<text>Marker Longhitude:<text><br>
<input id="userLng" type="text" name="userlng"  /><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Leaflet’s events](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events):

```
marker.on('click', function(e) {
    alert('Event is printed out to console');
    console.log(e);
});
```

So your code is to be modified as:

```
function getInfo() { 
    $.getJSON("get_info.php", function (data) { 
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng); 
        var marker = new L.Marker(location,{icon:Icon1}); 
           marker.bindPopup(
              data[i].name + "<br>" + 
              data[i].user_date + "<br>" + 
              data[i].user_time + "<br>" + 
              data[i].address + "<br>"
           ).addTo(map);
           marker.on('click', function(e) { // HERE YOU GO
             alert('Event is printed out to console'); // THIS CODE IS TO BE CHANGED
             console.log(e);                           // TO UPDATE WHATEVER YOU WANT
           });
         } 
    }); 
  }
```

Comment: Sorry Sir for my Question. How can I insert your code in my code?

Comment: See update. You still need to write the code for updating textboxes yourself. Nobody here will write the code for you.

Comment: Sir I already updated my post that will transfer the markers lat/long in two textbox but when i try it nothing happens. I just follow your instruction. Please see my edited post

Comment: What `markerA` states for in your update? It seems to be a typo, the var name is still `marker`?

Comment: sir sorry for the typo. I just remove the A from markerA and it works perfectly. TYSM and sorry for the wrong code, anyway i just edited my post for future use, TY

Comment: Sir May I ask again one more? Ahhm when I try your code it works Ok since I have many markers so when i move my cursor in different markers the value of lat/long doesnt change. It only gets the first marker but the next one doesnt change.

Comment: This is another issue which is described here in details: http://www.apaxsoftware.com/2012/05/common-javascript-mistakes-loops-and-callbacks/